# how to debug FreePascal in VSCode

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb, freepascal

As I use VSCode to code for Pascal language and I have installed some extensions to debug my program. I use [Native Debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=webfreak.debug) for debugging. I have consulted several tutorials on the net but with no success. Tell me what is the error here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7BOc.png)

My json files:

**launch.json**

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "target": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            // "terminal": "",
            "valuesFormatting": "parseText",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\FPC\\3.2.2\\bin\\i386-win32\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "fpc: Build Debug",
            "postDebugTask": "fpc: Clean Files"
        },
    ]
}
```

and **tasks.json**

```json
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    { // shortcut: cmd+shift+B (run build task)
      "label"  : "fpc: Build Debug",
      "type"   : "shell",
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "command": "fpc",
      "args": [
        "${file}",      // source code file
        "-Px86_64",     // target platform 64-bit
        "-Mobjfpc",     // object pascal mode
        "-S2cahi",      // pascal syntax setting
        "-Croti",       // generated code setting
        "-O1",          // code optimization setting
        "-glpsw3",      // debug info setting
        "-godwarfcpp",  // dwarf mode setting
        "-v"            // verbose message
      ],
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
    { // shortcut: none
      "label"  : "fpc: Build Release",
      "type"   : "shell",
      "group"  : "build",
      "command": "fpc",
      "args": [
        "${file}",      // source code file
        "-Px86_64",     // target platform 64-bit
        "-Mobjfpc",     // object pascal mode
        "-S2cahi",      // pascal syntax setting
        "-Croti",       // generated code setting
        "-O3",          // code optimization setting
        "-XXs",         // executable setting
        "-v"            // verbose message
      ],
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
    { // shortcut: none
      "label": "fpc: Syntax Check",
      "type": "shell",
      "group": "build",
      "command": "fpc",
      "args": [
        "${file}",      // source code file
        "-Px86_64",     // target platform 64-bit
        "-Mobjfpc",     // object pascal mode
        "-S2cahi",      // pascal syntax setting
        "-s",           // syntax check mode
        "-v"            // verbose message
      ],
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
    { // shortcut: cmd+shift+R (run test task)
      "label": "fpc: Execute Binary",
      "type": "shell",
      "group": {
        "kind": "test",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "command": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "args": [],
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
    { // shortcut: none
      "label": "fpc: Clean Files",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "rm",
      "args": [
        "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",  // executable file
        "${fileDirname}/*.a",          // generated linker file
        "${fileDirname}/*.o",          // generated object file
        "${fileDirname}/*.exe",
        "${fileDirname}/*.s",          // generated assembler file
        "${fileDirname}/*.ppu",        // generated unit file
        "${fileDirname}/*.dwarf",      // generated dwarf debug file
        "*.res",                       // generated resource file
        "ppas.bat",                    // generated build script file
      ],
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using windows operating system. help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you use a 64-bit FPC (target), but only have a 32-bit GDB (see miDebuggerPath in launch.json) installed in your VSCode.  See if you can point nativedebug to a 64-bit GDB.

If needed, you can find 64-bit gdb's for use with Lazarus here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Windows%2064%20bits/Alternative%20GDB/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I downloaded the GDB in the link above and it seems to work. But I can set breakpoints in my code. What is the reason here?

Comment: Make sure that (1) you select the debug profile, and then do a full build. (2) learn how to accept answers :-)